# Completely incongruent box partitions

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, recreational-mathematics

Let $B$ be a rectangular box with corners in $\mathbb{Z}^d$
and sides parallel to the axes.
A *completely incongruent* partition of $B$ is a partition into
$d$-dimensional boxes, each of whose integer side lengths is unique.
For example, here is such a partition of a $9 \times 17$ rectangle
in $\mathbb{Z}^2$:

---

[image: IncongruentPartition]

          

<sup>Based on Fig.7.2.3 in Claudi & Nelsen.<sup>1</sup>
The lengths $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ are used, none repeating.</sup>

---

I know from Claudi & Nelsen<sup>1</sup> that completely incongruent
partitions of rectangles in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and boxes in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ are
known (they call them "perfectly decomposed" boxes).
My question is whether or not there is any reason to expect that, for
each dimension $d$, there exists at least one box with a completely
incongruent partition into $d$-dimensional boxes.
It seems the condition that all side lengths be distinct integers might
be difficult to formulate in a manner that could lead to an answer 
to this question.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Alsina, Claudi, and Roger B. Nelsen. *A Mathematical Space Odyssey: Solid Geometry in the 21st Century*. Vol. 50. The Mathematical Association of America, 2015.

Comment: I do not feel any difficulty mentioned in the last paragraph. If you ever have a partition into boxes with _real_ side lengths such that all lengths of co-directed sides are distinct, you may achieve what you want. Indeed, partitions of one combinatorial type are determined by a system of linear equations with rational coefficients (with positivity assumptions on the variables being added), and a neighborhood of an arbitrary solution of such a system contains a rational solution. Finally, one may trivially rescale different directions differently.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: That is convincing reasoning---Thanks!